# Calling a class's __init__ attributes and appending to that attribute

Tags: python

I'm trying to append an item to an argument of an external class which is a list but I need to create an instance. But how do I create an instance to that class's arguments  without using that same class instance? here is a little example of what I'm trying to do

```
  class A(object):
      def __init__(self, list1, arg1)
          self.list1 = list1
          self.arg1 = arg1

  class B(object):
      def __init__(self, arg2, arg3)
          self.arg2 = arg2
          self.arg3 = arg3

      def method1(self, arg4)
          self.arg4 = arg4
          if 0 < 1:
              A(A.list1, A.arg1).list1.append('newitem')
          return list1
```

What should I do to append that newItem to list1?

I'm sorry if i don't explain myself well. i'm really confused

EDIT (adding my actual code)

```
class SimpleVirus(object):

    def __init__(self, maxBirthProb, clearProb):
        self.maxBirthProb = maxBirthProb
        self.clearProb = clearProb


    def reproduce(self, popDensity):
        self.popDensity = popDensity 
        reproduceProb = self.getMaxBirthProb() * (1 - popDensity)
        child = SimpleVirus(self.getMaxBirthProb(),  self.getClearProb())
        VirusL = Patient.getVirusesList()
        if random.random() <= reproduceProb:
                #Down here is where I need to append to the "viruses" list
            Patient(viruses, maxPop).viruses.append(child)
            return child
        else: 
            raise NoChildException()


class Patient(object):

    def __init__(self, viruses, maxPop): #viruses is a list

        self.viruses = viruses
        self.maxPop = maxPop
```

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology is confused; "call a class argument" doesn't mean anything to me.

Your code is broken as is; you have `list1` and `arg1` in `A.__init__` parameter list but you use `arg2` in the body. Please use meaningful names in examples, and cut-and-paste the actual code you're running, as well as the actual error message you get.

What do you want the `A`'s `list1` and `arg2` to be prior to appending the string? If, for example, you want an empty list to append to and a zero for `arg2`, then do:

```
A([],0).list1.append('newitem')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand your code. This part should be deleted as it doesn't mean anything:

```
self.arg4 = arg4
```

You define and initialize your class variables in the **init** method alone. Here arg4 is an input to your method and you'll only refer to it by its name alone, so no need for that line.

This part is also problematic:

```
A(A.list1, A.arg1).list1.append('newitem')
```

First you have to create an *instance* or *object* of the class and only then append something to one of its variables. So the best way is to assume arg4 is an instance of the class A:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, list1, arg1):
      self.list1 = list1
      self.arg1 = arg1

class B(object):
  def __init__(self, arg2, arg3):
      self.arg2 = arg2
      self.arg3 = arg3
  def method1(self, arg4):
      if 0 < 1:
          arg4.list1.append('newitem')
      return arg4.list1
```

Here's how you can test it in the python shell.

```
>>> arg = A ([],1)
>>> b = B(2,3)
>>> b.method1(arg)
['newitem']
>>>
```

First I created an instance of the class A with the name arg. Then an object of the class B with the name b. Finally I called the b's method1 with the argument being arg.